# Removing Old JPG and MP3 Files From Bundle

Tags: iphone, bundle, simulator

I think this is very basic, but still, I didn't understand what I should do here:
In my app there are many JPG and MP3 files stored in the app bundle; they are triggered and displayed upon user actions. When I change a certain file (for example, I had a photo and I wanted to change it to a new photo with the same file name instead of the one I had), I delete it from the bundle (selecting "Also Move to Trash") and then insert the new file.

In some cases (not always) the old file is simply not disappearing (!?!); If I look in the bundle I see the new photo, but when I run the the Simulator I still see the old photo (same goes with mp3 files).

anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should delete the app in simulator and re-install it to simulator by Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

When Installing app in simulator, Xcode doesn't delete old files, which can lead some troubles like this. Just make sure to :

- delete app from simulator
- OR reset simulator
- OR (the one I prefer) delete app directly from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/_version_/Applications`

Answer (score 0):

Build>>Clean & Build>>Clean all targets will solve your issue.

Do these two things and then compile and run the app and you'll see the changes.

Comment: For some reason in XCode in the Build menu the "Clean" and the "Clean all Targets" options are disabled and there is no "Clean & Build".
Is the Build menu where I'm supposed to be looking for "Clean & Build" or did you mean something else?